# waveInProc / Windows audio question

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, audio

I'm using the Windows API to get audio input.  I've followed all the steps on MSDN and managed to record audio to a WAV file.  No problem.  I'm using multiple buffers and all that.  I'd like to do more with the buffers than simply write to a file, so now I've got a callback set up.  It works great and I'm getting the data, but I'm not sure what to do with it once I have it.

Here's my callback... everything here works:

```
// Media API callback
void CALLBACK AudioRecorder::waveInProc(HWAVEIN hWaveIn, UINT uMsg, DWORD dwInstance, DWORD dwParam1, DWORD dwParam2)
{

    // Data received
    if (uMsg == WIM_DATA)
    {

        // Get wav header
        LPWAVEHDR mBuffer = (WAVEHDR *)dwParam1;

        // Now what?
        for (unsigned i = 0; i != mBuffer->dwBytesRecorded; ++i)
        {

            // I can see the char, how do get them into my file and audio buffers?
            cout << mBuffer->lpData[i] << "\n";

        }

        // Re-use buffer
        mResultHnd = waveInAddBuffer(hWaveIn, mBuffer, sizeof(mInputBuffer[0])); // mInputBuffer is a const WAVEHDR *

    }

}

// waveInOpen cannot use an instance method as its callback, 
// so we create a static method which calls the instance version
void CALLBACK AudioRecorder::staticWaveInProc(HWAVEIN hWaveIn, UINT uMsg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2)
{

    // Call instance version of method
    reinterpret_cast<AudioRecorder *>(dwParam1)->waveInProc(hWaveIn, uMsg, dwInstance, dwParam1, dwParam2);

}
```

Like I said, it works great, but I'm trying to do the following:

- Convert the data to short and copy into an array
- Convert the data to float and copy into an array
- Copy the data to a larger char array which I'll write into a WAV
- Relay the data to an arbitrary output device

I've worked with FMOD a lot and I'm familiar with interleaving and all that.  But FMOD dishes everything out as floats.  In this case, I'm going the other way.  I guess I'm basically just looking for resources on how to go from LPSTR to short, float, and unsigned char.

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the help!  I know it's a pretty general question so I appreciate the specific answers.  Back to work and will mark an answer/respond soon.

Comment: One word of caution: The wave APIs are quite finicky - you can't do too much work inside the wave procedure.  The warning on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909756.aspx) is quite clear: calling wave* functions (like waveInAddBuffer) from a callback is highly likely to deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct { 
    LPSTR      lpData; 
    // etc..
} WAVEHDR;
```

Hmya, awkward type there.  It isn't a STR of course, should have been a PVOID.  Just cast it to whatever type you need:

```
short* data = (short*)(mBuffer->lpData);
unsigned samples = mBuffer->dwBytesRecorded / sizeof(short);
// etc..
```

Comment: Sweet, this just helped me understand this much more.

Answer (score 3):

Convering 8/16/32 bits/sample array to floats-array:

```
void src_BYTE_to_float_array(const unsigned char* in, float* out, int len)
{
    while (len)
    {
        len--;
        out[len]= (float) (in [len] / (1.0 * 0x80) -1.0);
    }
}

void src_short_to_float_array(const short* in, float* out, int len)
{
    while (len)
    {
        len--;
        out[len]= (float) (in [len] / (1.0 * 0x8000)) ;
    }
}

void src_int_to_float_array(const int* in, float* out, int len)
{
    while (len)
    {
        len--;
        out[len]= (float) (in [len] / (8.0 * 0x10000000)) ;
    }
}
```

To play the samples, you'll have to do the opposite:

```
void src_float_to_BYTE_array(const float* in, unsigned char* out, int len)
{
    double scaled_value;

    while (len)
    {
        len--;

        scaled_value= in[len] * (8.0 * 0x10000000);
        if (scaled_value >= (1.0 * 0x7FFFFFFF))
        {
            out[len]= 255;
            continue ;
        }

        out[len]= (unsigned char)((lrint(scaled_value) >> 24) + 0x80);
    }
}

void src_float_to_short_array(const float* in, short* out, int len)
{   
    double scaled_value;

    while (len)
    {
        len--;

        scaled_value= in[len] * (8.0 * 0x10000000);
        if (scaled_value >= (1.0 * 0x7FFFFFFF))
        {
            out[len]= 32767;
            continue ;
        }

        out[len]= (short)(lrint(scaled_value) >> 16);
    }
}

void src_float_to_int_array(const float* in, int* out, int len)
{   
    double scaled_value;

    while (len)
    {
        len--;

        scaled_value= in[len] * (8.0 * 0x10000000);
        if (scaled_value >= (1.0 * 0x7FFFFFFF))
        {
            out[len]= 0x7fffffff;
            continue;
        }

        out[len]= lrint(scaled_value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done all this but it's a just too much info to explain it all in detail here. I suggest you take a look at the [source code of PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/archives/pa_stable_v19_20071207.tar.gz): it's a pretty good implementation of MME, although some parts are a bit too messy to my liking, but it contains everything you're after, including the conversions.

- converting the data: it depends on your input format. The MME buffer stores everything in a char*, but that doesn't mean the actual samples are chars. They might be 8, 16, 24, 32 (int or float) or 64 bit (float). Conversion from one integer to another one of different size is usually done using a simple bit shift. Converting integer to float is nomally done by first converting the integer to float using a simple cast, than dividing it by the max value of that integer in order to get a number between -1.0 and 1.0. This is also called normalizing. You can also add dithering to all these conversions.
- buffering the data: you don't want to spent much time in the callback or you'll drop buffers, so disk I/O in the callback is not done. Imo a circular buffer combined with producer/consumer pattern is the most convenient to solve this: the buffer gets filled (using simple memcpy which is pretty fast) in the MME callback, which then signals another thread. Upon being signalled that thread checks how much data is in the buffer, and writes it to a file if it's enough (you don't want to write small pieces to the file each time, instead wait for a large chunk of data and dump it at once). This way you seperate the slow disk I/O from the callback.
- get the data to output device: just like you have a waveInProc, you'll have a waveOutProc for the output. In that callback you're supposed to write the data to be output to the buffer.